# Multiple Jquery .delegate() problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, delegates, get

I have multiple jquery delegate functions to delete items from lists. They work fine for the first time, but seem to stop to the delete function working for the other delete functions.

So I have 3 tables, availability,experience and hobby. If i click to delete an item from the hobby list it works, and diasbles the others from working. Subsequent deletes from hobby still works.

Having looked at it with firebug, it seems each click to delete an entry from availability or experience is triggering the same link that was first triggered to delete from  hobby as if it has saved it and won't change it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;
    var pager;
    var pai;
    var thetab;
    $('#tabs-5').delegate('.delav', 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        pager = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#dialog2").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 600,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function () {
                    $('#ava_list').html("Loading..");

                    pai = $('#epa_id').val();
                    thetab = "availability";
                    $.get("/_includes/functions.php", {
                        cache: false,
                        table: thetab,
                        pa: pai,
                        delattr: pager
                    }, function (data) {
                        $('#ava_list').html(data);
                    });

                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        $("#dialog2").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;
    var pager;
    var pai;
    var thetab;
    $('#tabs-3').delegate('.delexp', 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        pager = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#dialog2").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 600,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function () {
                    $('#exp_list').html("Loading..");

                    pai = $('#epa_id').val();
                    thetab = "";
                    $.get("/_includes/functions.php?ms=", {
                        cache: false,
                        table: thetab,
                        pa: pai,
                        delattr: pager
                    }, function (data) {
                        $('#exp_list').html(data);
                    });

                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        $("#dialog2").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;
    var pager;
    var pai;
    var thetab;
    $('#tabs-7').delegate('.delhob', 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        pager = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#dialog2").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 600,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function () {
                    $('#hob_list').html("Loading..");

                    pai = $('#epa_id').val();
                    thetab = "hobby";
                    $.get("/_includes/functions.php", {
                        cache: false,
                        table: thetab,
                        pa: pai,
                        delattr: pager
                    }, function (data) {
                        $('#hob_list').html(data);
                    });

                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        $("#dialog2").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: Not clear whether the click on delete triggers the proper event handler or not... anyway you repeat nearly the same code (except from the selectors as far as I can see) with the same var names three times, and that makes it more difficult to debug. You should try to refactor it and avoid repetitions...

Comment: all of them work to trigger the delete function. If a refresh my page then trigger a delete event on availability, experience or hobby, they all work. Which ever is first used works - then seems to stop the others from working. I also have an add function for each of them - this works fine regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest first making the following changes to drastically simplify the problem and to make it less likely that one dialog can conflict with the others:

1. Get rid of all the duplicate code and collapse all your code to a single function call with a few parameters.
2. Make sure you destroy the previously used dialog so when you create a new one, it's created from scratch with your new data.

And a few questions.  What are the `table:`, `pa:` and `delattr:` attributes doing in the get object passed to the $.get function?  They aren't documented `$.get()` settings.  Also, do you mean all three dialogs to have identical `pa: $('#epa_id').val(),` lines in them?

Here's how you can collapse all your duplicate code into one common function and use unique IDs for each dialog.  I've also removed local variables that weren't needed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function configureDialogClick(parent, child, list, tab, dialogID) {
        $(parent).delegate(child, 'click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var pager = $(this).attr("href");
            $(dialogID).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 600,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Confirm": function () {
                        $(list).html("Loading..");

                        $.get("/_includes/functions.php", {
                            cache: false,
                            table: tab,
                            pa: $('#epa_id').val(),
                            delattr: pager
                        }, function (data) {
                            $(list).html(data);
                        });

                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        $(this).dialog('destroy');
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        $(this).dialog('destroy');
                    }
                }
            });
            $(dialogID).dialog("open");
        });
    }

    configureDialogClick("#tabs-3", ".delexp", "#ava_list", "", "#dialog3");
    configureDialogClick("#tabs-5", ".delav", "#hob_list", "availability", "#dialog5");
    configureDialogClick("#tabs-7", ".delhob", "#hob_list", "hobby", "#dialog7");

});
```

Since I have no way of running this code, I can't say whether this fixes the issue or it's just the next cleanup step in the right direction.

Comment: There is probably a far easier method to achieve the same thing - apologies for my code as jquery is fairly new to me so I seem to have a 'hacky' approach. After having looked at this new code you written above I see that you are pointing to the problem being related to the dialog box..

So I made further checks. And yes - this dialog box (confirm/cancel) is used elsewhere, and malfunctions there too. So just to try and get it working, before overhauling the code - is there a way I can get it to work by stopping the dialog from using the same get url each time?

Comment: Also if im being honest, the most ideal way would be to have the full get query pulled from the href of a link which would allow me to simply add a dialog to any link with a specified class which would save me alot of code throughout. I had problems with this though so opted for writing everything the long way to get it all working.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your new question.  If you want a different URL each time for the get, you just have to change the code to modify the get URL for each specific case.  It's hard for me to know how to advise you on modifying the code if you don't include the relevant HTML and describe what you want the get URL to be.

Comment: Sorry I was thinking outloud...

If those full 'get' URL's were to be stored in the 'href; of each delete link, then I would lose the need for all variables except the PA variable... so I could then have a new function to simply run the href of a link <a href="functions.php?table=hobby&pa=1..." class="ajaxme">Delete</a> From what you have previously said, the problem lies with using the same dialog, which is a problem for me as I would struggle to create these dialogs on the fly, unless the function that is triggered does a clone of the original dialog and then deletes it afterwards

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand how my revised code automatically creates a different dialog for each click handler just by virtue of passing in different IDs.  Did you try the revised code?

Comment: Hi sorry, I was a little reserved about changing up the whole code without having managed to correct it, I have made a couple of edits - and yes it works in the way of reducing the three sets of functions down, but I had to specify dialog2 to get it to work on the first.... that dialog is already created in the html and hidden, so id have to clone it or dynamically create a new one to use different id's?

Comment: Ahhh, so you are using the same dialog for each.  I think you can reuse dialog2, if you just remove it after close so that it gets destroyed and will get created anew each time.  As I've added in my code above, try adding `$(this).dialog('destroy');` after the close.

Comment: a-haaaaa! Yes!.. Thankyou very much! - I was close to rethinking my use of lots of jquery on this project, and I didnt think anyone understood the issue. I will post you the final working code if you would like to put it into an answer box so I can accept it etc? really helped me out here ##edit - sorry I am not able to move to chat. but i basically corrected the three calls to configure function, removed parent and dialog id from the whole thing and added the destroy line.

Comment: If the destroy was the key, you can just accept the answer we have now since that has it in it.  I've edited my answer to include the info on destroy.